# When is UML designer 8 released?

Tags: uml-designer

I thought UML designer 8 should have been released in July, including the UML generator.
So far I cannot find it.

Anyone knows when it will be released?

Answer (score 0):

The version 8.0 will be released at the end of the month you can have a look at the milestones on GitHub: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/milestones
You can try the beta by downloading the nightly version available on the download page:
http://www.umldesigner.org/download/

Comment: thx, though the download link does not contain the nightly builds.
Does the sequence diagram now contain fragments?

Comment: The nightly build is available from the download page, have a look at the all versions section, in the table see the last row "nightly". There is no fragments in the sequence diagram, if you need them, please fill an issue in the bug tracker.